# Permutative Constraint on Image Approximation

Tags: matrices, optimization, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, image-processing

### Motivation

I am trying to explore the idea of constraining the approximation of an image represented by an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ by the values on a linearly-spaced interval of $mn$ elements $L$ generated over the unit interval $I=[0,1)$.

### Goal

I want to use each element of $L$ once and only once in filling an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $B$. I want to minimize the function

$$f = \sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n{|A_{ij}-B_{ij}|}$$

so each $B_{ij}$ is constrained by the minimization of $f$ and by the bijection induced by its uniqueness in $L$.

### Naive Approach

Evaluate the error for all $(mn)!$ choices of $B$.

### Question

Computationally-speaking, what is the best algorithm for finding $B$? What is the computational complexity class of that algorithm? How hard is this to do in an approximate way? Is there a greedy algorithm for this?

Comment: Please define "linearly-spaced interval of $m n$ elements".

Comment: Complexity classes are for decision problems, not algorithms.